# flex3 button state

Tags: css, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

I would like to change the state of a flex button component with actionscript (on the fly) to present it as mouse-down/mouse-over/mouse-up, in order to use the css skining with out the existence of the mouse cursor.
I tried to do this with button.currentState but this doesn't work.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [styles](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/Button.html#styleSummary) to set the skins, not states.

If you want to display those states on the fly, you could dispatch the events form the buttons when you need to.

e.g.

```
//do roll over
yourButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER));
//do roll out
yourButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT));
//do press
yourButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN));
//do release
yourButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer!
I was actually using styles but I would like now to find a way to emulate button click from an other event. To do this I have to trigger is some way the style of the button to be, lets say downSkin style.
And I can't figure out how to do this. 

thanks again

Comment: try dispatching events from you button instance